# Fundamental group of punctured simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, fundamental-group

([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258252) is originally from Math.SE where it was suggested that I ask the question here)

Let $S$ be a simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x$ be an interior point of $S$, meaning that $B_r(x)\subseteq S$ for some $r>0$.
Is it necessarily the case that $\pi_1(S\setminus\{x\})\cong\mathbb{Z}$?

This is true if $S$ is open by the Riemann mapping theorem.
Moishe Kohan's answer on Math.SE shows that the result holds if $S$ is compact.

---

Let $B=B_r(x)$ and let $G=\pi_1(S\setminus\{x\})$.
I can show that $G^{ab}\cong\mathbb{Z}$.
Consider the commutative diagram of topological spaces
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}B\setminus\{x\}&\ra{}&S\setminus\{x\}&\ra{}&\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x\}\\\da{}&&\da{}\\B&\ra{}&S\end{array}
$$
Applying the fundamental group functor gives a commutative diagram of groups
$$
\begin{array}{c}\mathbb{Z}&\ra{}&G&\ra{}&\mathbb{Z}\\\da{}&&\da{}\\1&\ra{}&1\end{array}
$$
where the composition of the top two maps is the identity homomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}$.
By the Seifert-van Kampen theorem, the square is a pushout diagram of groups, meaning that the normal closure of the image of $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ is all of $G$.
In particular, if $A$ is an abelian group then any two homomorphisms $G\to A$ that agree on the image of $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ must agree on all of $G$.
Another way to put this is that if we have two homomorphisms $G\to A$ such that the two compositions $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$ are equal then the two homomorphisms $G\to A$ are equal.

I claim that the map $G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelianization map.
To see this, let $A$ be an abelian group and let $G\to A$ be a homomorphism.
Now recall that the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity.
Then the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$ agrees with the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$.
By the remark at the end of the previous paragraph, this means that the composition $G\to\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$ agrees with the map $G\to A$.
In other words, the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$ makes the abelianization diagram commute.

To show uniqueness, let $\mathbb{Z}\to A$ be a map making the abelianization diagram commute.
Then the composition $G\to\mathbb{Z}\to A$ agrees with the map $G\to A$.
Then the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to\mathbb{Z}\to A$ agrees with the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$.
Since the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity, this shows that the map $\mathbb{Z}\to A$ is given by the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to G\to A$.

This shows that the map $G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelianization map.

Comment: If the space is a connected CW complex it should be true. Since it’s simply connected, it’s weakly contractible. If it’s a CW complex then it’s contractible. By your assumption that it contains an open ball, the space has a $2$-cell, so the inclusion of the $2$-cell into your space is a homotopy equivalence. Removing the point in the interior of the $2$-cell should induce a homotopy equivalence of the punctured space with $S^1$

Comment: You might also mentioned the significant feedback you had on MathSE, notably that the result holds when $S$ is compact (and hence, more generally when every compact subset of $S$ is contained in a simply connected compact subset).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proof that $\pi_1(S\setminus\{x\})\cong\mathbb Z$. It is along similar lines to Jeremy Brazas' answer, and also makes use of Lemma 13 from the paper [*The fundamental groups of subsets of closed surfaces inject into their first shape groups*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512343v1https://).

> **Lemma 13**: Let any set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^2$, and map $\alpha\colon S^1\to A$ be given. Let $U$ be the unbounded connected component of $\mathbb R^2\setminus{\rm Im}(\alpha)$. If $\alpha\colon S^1\to A$ is null-homotopic, then so is $\alpha\colon S^1\to A\setminus U$.

As we know, the embedding $B_r(x)\setminus\{x\}\to\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$ gives an isomorphism of fundamental groups, which are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. Hence, the embeddings $B_r(x)\setminus\{x\}\to S\setminus\{x\}\to\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$ gives homomorphisms
$$
\mathbb Z\stackrel{f}{\to}\pi_1(S\setminus\{x\})\stackrel{g}{\to}\mathbb Z
$$
with $gf=\iota$. To show that $f,g$ are isomorphisms, it is enough to show that $g$ has trivial kernel. So, suppose that $g([\gamma])=0$ for some closed curve $\gamma\colon S^1\to S\setminus\{x\}$. This means that $\gamma$ is null-homotopic in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$.

Letting $U$ be the unbounded connected component of $\mathbb R^2\setminus{\rm Im}(\gamma)$, Lemma 13 states that $\gamma$ is null-homotopic in $\mathbb R^2\setminus(U\cup\{x\})$. If we can show that $\mathbb R^2\setminus U\subseteq S$ then we are done. It is enough to show that each bounded connected component $V$ of $\mathbb R^2\setminus{\rm Im}(\gamma)$ is contained in $S$.

From the proof of Lemma 13 in the linked paper, $V$ is simply connected and, by the Riemann mapping theorem, there is a conformal $h\colon\mathbb D\to V$ with boundary map $h\vert_{\partial\mathbb D}$ mapping to $\partial V\subseteq {\rm Im}(\gamma)\subseteq S$. By shrinking this down to a circle in $\mathbb D$, we see that it has winding number $1$ about every point in $V$, so cannot be null-homotopic in $S$ unless $V\subseteq S$.
[I was hoping to complete this proof only using the statement of Lemma 13, but it is a bit trickier than expected, so had to refer to the proof of the lemma from the linked paper].

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $B(x,r)\backslash \{x\}$ is a retract of $S\backslash\{x\}$ and so the inclusion $B(x,r)\backslash\{x\}\to S\backslash \{x\}$ induces an injection on $\pi_1$. I will argue below that the induced homomorphism is also surjective, giving $\pi_1(S\backslash\{x\})\cong\mathbb{Z}$.

**Claim:** The inclusion $B(x,r)\backslash\{x\}\to S\backslash \{x\}$ induces a surjection on fundamental groups.

*Proof.* Suppose $S\neq \mathbb{R}^2$ and take $r$ to be the maximum radius such that $B(x,r)\subseteq S$.

Case 1: there exists a point $y\in \overline{B}(x,r)\backslash S$.

Suppose $\alpha:[0,1]\to S\backslash \{x\}$ is a path such that

- $\alpha(0)=a_0$ and $\alpha(1)=a_1$ lie in $B(x,r/2)\backslash B(x,r/3)$,
- $Im(\alpha)\cap B(x,r)$ is the union of two half-open arcs which lies in $B(x,r)\backslash B(x,r/3)$ and does not separate $x$ and $y$ in $B(x,r)\cup\{y\}$.

The Peano continuum $P=Im(\alpha)\cup \overline{B}(x,r/2)$ lies in $S$. If $y$ was in a bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash P$, then $S$ would not be simply connected. Therefore, $y$ must lie in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash (Im(\alpha)\cup B(x,r/2))$. Let $R$ be an infinite ray that consists of arc arc in $\overline{B}(x,r)$ from $x$ to $y$ that does not meet $Im(\alpha)\cap B(x,r)$ and an infinite curve from $y$ off to infinity which does not meet $Im(\alpha)$. Now choose an arc $\beta$ from $a_1$ to $a_0$ in $B(x,r/2)\backslash R$. Since the loop $\alpha\cdot\beta$ does not meet the ray $R$, $R$ lies in the unbounded component $O$ of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash Im(\alpha\cdot\beta)$. Fischer and Zastrow define $I(\alpha\cdot\beta)=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash O$ to be the "inner region" of $\alpha\cdot\beta$ in Definition 11 of the paper [FZ] referenced below. Since $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is a loop that contracts in $S$, Lemma 13 in [FZ] guarantees that $\alpha\cdot\beta$ contracts in the set $S\cap I(\alpha\cdot\beta)$, which does not contain $x$. Therefore, $\alpha$ is homotopic to a path in $B(x,r/2)$ by a homotopy in $S$ that does not meet $x$.

Now given any loop $\ell$ in $S\backslash \{x\}$ based at a point in $B(x,r/2)\backslash B(x,r/3)$, one can finitely subdivide $\ell$ into segments that lie in $B(x,r/2)$ or lie in $S\backslash B(x,r/3)$. One can easily modify the subdivision and perform finitely many homotopies in the annular region to ensure that each subpath in $S\backslash B(x,r/3)$ is of the form $\alpha$ from above, i.e. satisfying the two bullet points. Applying the previous paragraph to these subpaths, we see that $\ell$ is path-homotopic in $S\backslash \{x\}$ to a loop in $B(x,r)\backslash \{x\}$.

Case 2: $\overline{B}(x,r)\subseteq S$. Notice that there exists points $y_n\notin S$ that converge to a point in the boundary circle $\partial\overline{B}(x,r)$. Suppose $\alpha:[0,1]\to S\backslash\{x\}$ is a path such that $\alpha((0,1))\cap \overline{B}(x,r)=\emptyset$ and $\alpha(0),\alpha(1)\in \partial\overline{B}(x,r)$. Let $\beta:[0,1]\to\partial\overline{B}(x,r)$ be the shortest arc on the boundary circle from $\alpha(1)$ to $\alpha(0)$. Consider the loop $\alpha\cdot\beta$ and it's inner region $I(\alpha\cdot\beta)$. If there exists a ray $R$ containing the line segment from $x$ to a point $y\in\partial\overline{B}(x,r)$ and an infinite curve from $y$ to $\infty$ that lies in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash Im (\alpha\cdot\beta))$, then we may proceed as before (using Lemma 13) to contract $\alpha\cdot\beta$ in $S\backslash\{x\}$. If there is no such ray, then a neighborhood of $\overline{B}(x,r)$ must lie in $I(\alpha\cdot\beta)$. However, this forces a bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash Im(\alpha\cdot\beta)$ to contain a point $y_n$ and contradicts that $S$ is simply connected. Thus, we can always contract $\alpha\cdot\beta$ within $S\cap I(\alpha\cdot\beta)\backslash \{x\}$ as desired.

Now if $\ell$ is any loop in $S\backslash\{x\}$ based at a point in $B(x,r)$, then we consider the open set $\ell^{-1}(S\backslash \overline{B}(x,r))$, which might have countably many components. If $(a,b)$ is such a component, then $\alpha=\ell|_{[a,b]}$ is path-homotopic to the shortest arc $\beta$ along $\partial \overline{B}(x,r)$ from $\alpha(a)$ to $\alpha(b)$. In particular, the homotopy used may be chosen to be of the form $[a,b]\times [0,1]\to I(\alpha\cdot\beta^{-1})$. Since we chose this homotopy to have size relative to that of $\alpha$, the diameters of the homotopies used goes to $0$ and we may glue them together to form a homotopy of $\ell$ to a loop entirely in $\overline{B}(x,r)\backslash \{x\}$. Of course, such a loop can then be deformed into $B(x,r)\backslash \{x\}$
 $\square$

Patching up this proof felt like whack-a-mole, and I fully admit it's probably not the most elegant approach, but I think the core idea is sound. At the end of the day, the results in [FZ] should take care of this problem.

[FZ] H. Fischer, A.Zastrow, *[The fundamental groups of
subsets of closed surfaces inject into their first shape groups](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513796494)*, Algebraic
and Geometric Topology 5 (2005) 1655-1676.

Comment: My impression is that this argument only proves that the quotient of $\pi_1(U)$ by the normal closure of some cyclic (retract) subgroup is trivial.

Comment: More precisely it is not true that given a path-connected space $X$ with a collared circle $C$ (i.e., with a closed subset homeomorphic to $C\times [0,1]$ with $C\times [0,1[$ being open in $X$, the "collared circle" being the copy of $C\times\{0\}$, assuming that gluing a disc along $C$ yields a simply connected space, does not imply that $X$ has cyclic fundamental group, and even if one assumes that $\pi_1(X)$ is torsion-free and that $\pi_1(C)$ is a retract subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: You are right, a more geometric argument is required.

Comment: To elaborate on @YCor's first comment: if $G=\langle x,y|yx=xy^2\rangle$ then the pushout of $1\xleftarrow{}\langle x\rangle\to G$ is $1$, but $\langle x\rangle$ is an infinite cyclic group and a retract of $G$ as we see by sending $y$ to $1$.

Comment: I apologize to everyone for editing this so much. This problem is far more interesting and delicate than I had anticipated. I'm cautiously hopeful that this new argument will either be a solution or lead to one.

Comment: I haven't gone through your answer in detail, but I am aware of a reasonably direct proof using Lemma 13 from the quoted paper (as I used in this math.SE answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3313163/1321)

Comment: I see you are using Lemma 13 already, so we are along the same lines, but I think it can be simplified. You need to show that a null-homotopic closed curve in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{x\}$ and lying in $S$ is also null-homotopic in $S\setminus\{x\}$, which follows from the lemma.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I feel like my argument is a fairly direct use of the Lemma but the difficulty I ran into is that you have no real control of what the image of a loop in $S\backslash\{x\}$ looks like or how it relates to $x$ and Lemma 13 requires a particular relationship between this image set and $x$. I found that it required a little finagling to make sure that $x$ actually ends up in the unbounded component of the inner region of a loop.

Comment: Why does there exist a point $y\in\overline{B}(x,r)\setminus S$? What if $S$ is a closed ball?

Comment: Yes, something here will need to be fixed for the case when $S$ includes $\overline{B}(x,r)$ with other things attached. If $S$ is just a closed ball, the conclusion is pretty obvious.

Comment: ok, I added my proof, but it worked out a bit trickier than expected.